# How to combine two OR statements with AND conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is what I wanted to create a formula for, but always getting error:

```
IF(AND(N2=0,O2=1),"Standard","Non-standard Change")
```

Or:

```
IF(AND(N2=1,O2=1),"Standard","Non-standard Change")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since O2 must be the same in both cases, you could do this:

```
IF(AND(OR(N2=0,N2=1),O2=1),"Standard","Non-standard Change")
```

Comment: Ahha, that worked! Thanks much :) Appreciate the help.